Cannot verify RSA signature with mbedTLS
I am integrating mbedTLS 2.14.1 on a bare-metal application running on an old ColdFire processor. This is an old version of mbedTLS but it was already used in my company for other projects.
The signature is generated by a HSM (Hadrware Security Module) following PKCS#1 2.1 PSS padding scheme. it has been verified using openssl with the following command line:
openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey pub.pem -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -pkeyopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -in sha256.bin -sigfile signature.bin

As a first step  I just added the public key, SHA256 and signature in my software and tried to verify the signature. The key is stored as a string (pem format, lines separated by \n) and the hash and signature as array of bytes extracted by hexdump -C from sha256.bin and signature.bin files.
unsigned char memory_buff[60000];
static const unsigned char pubKey [] = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n xxx \n etc... \n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
unsigned char sha256[32] = {0x12, ...};
unsigned char signature[512] = {0x34,  ...};
mbedtls_pk_context pk_pub;

/* don't use dynamic allocation */
mbedtls_memory_buffer_alloc_init( (unsigned char *)memory_buff, sizeof(memory_buff) );

/* context init */
mbedtls_pk_init(&pk_pub);

/* key parsing */
ret = mbedtls_pk_parse_public_key( (mbedtls_pk_context *)&pk_pub, pubKey, strlen((const char *)pubKey) + 1);
if( ret != 0 )
{        
    /* do something */
}

/* padding PKCS#1 2.1 */
mbedtls_rsa_set_padding(mbedtls_pk_rsa(pk_pub), MBEDTLS_RSA_PKCS_V21, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256);


ret = mbedtls_rsa_pkcs1_verify( (mbedtls_rsa_context *)pk_pub.pk_ctx, NULL, NULL, MBEDTLS_RSA_PUBLIC, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256, 0, sha256, signature );
if( ret != 0 )
{        
    /* do something */
}

The configuration of mbedTLS is:
#define MBEDTLS_HAVE_INT32
#define MBEDTLS_NO_UDBL_DIVISION
/* #define MBEDTLS_HAVE_TIME*/
/* #define MBEDTLS_HAVE_TIME_DATE */
#define MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_MEMORY
#define MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_NO_STD_FUNCTIONS
#define MBEDTLS_ENTROPY_HARDWARE_ALT
#define MBEDTLS_REMOVE_ARC4_CIPHERSUITES
#define MBEDTLS_NO_PLATFORM_ENTROPY
/*#define MBEDTLS_SELF_TEST*/
#define MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_FPRINTF_MACRO
#define MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_PRINTF_MACRO
#define MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_SNPRINTF_MACRO snprintf
#define MBEDTLS_VERSION_FEATURES
#define MBEDTLS_AES_C
#define MBEDTLS_CIPHER_MODE_CBC
#define MBEDTLS_AES_ROM_TABLES
#define MBEDTLS_ARC4_C
#define MBEDTLS_ASN1_PARSE_C
#define MBEDTLS_ASN1_WRITE_C
#define MBEDTLS_BASE64_C
#define MBEDTLS_BIGNUM_C
#define MBEDTLS_CERTS_C
/*#define MBEDTLS_CIPHER_C*/
#define MBEDTLS_CTR_DRBG_C
#define MBEDTLS_ENTROPY_C
#define MBEDTLS_ERROR_C
#define MBEDTLS_HMAC_DRBG_C
#define MBEDTLS_MD_C
#define MBEDTLS_MEMORY_BUFFER_ALLOC_C
#define MBEDTLS_OID_C
/*#define MBEDTLS_PADLOCK_C*/
#define MBEDTLS_PEM_PARSE_C
#define MBEDTLS_PEM_WRITE_C
#define MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_C
#define MBEDTLS_SHA1_C
#define MBEDTLS_SHA256_C
#define MBEDTLS_VERSION_C

#define MBEDTLS_PKCS1_V21
#define MBEDTLS_PKCS1_V15

#define MBEDTLS_RSA_C
#define MBEDTLS_BIGNUM_C
#define MBEDTLS_OID_C

#define MBEDTLS_PK_C
#define MBEDTLS_PK_PARSE_C

I get an error MBEDTLS_ERR_RSA_VERIFY_FAILED.
There is probably a mistake in my usage of mbedTLS, do you have an idea ?

Works on my machine. May be due to your data. Post some test data.

I cannot post the key even if it's public key but I will try with another pair of RSA keys. You computed the signature with openssl and verified it with my code example ?

Yes. I created the signature with OpenSSL and successfully verified it with your OpenSSL statement. I then successfully verified the signature with your code (with mbedTLS v2.14.1).

OK I just test my sample code directly on Linux with my data and indeed it works (should have done it before). So there is a difference when compililng and running on coldfire.

The error in the verification was due to my configuration of the lib. Since the stack is limited on my target I reduced MBETLS_MPI_WINDOW_SIZE to 4 (instead of 6) and MBEDTLS_MPI_MAX_SIZE to 512 (instead of 1024).
With original config the verification is OK
